# Running Symfony2 command in background

Tags: bash, symfony

Let's say I have Symfony2 Command example:command.
It works fine, when I type in terminal:

```
php app/console example:command &
```

But if I trying to do it with sh file, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
php app/console example:command &
```

it does not work. What may cause the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by _does not work_?

Comment: have you tried using absolute path in sh file?

Comment: There is no output, but `ps aux` says that process didn't start.

Comment: yes, I've tried with absolute path - it wasn't a fix.

Answer (score 2):

(I assume your Symfony path is /var/www/Symfony/ ) In sh file try this

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/Symfony/app/console example:command
```

If you want to run it in crontab as well, you need to redirect the the Symfony folder by `cd` then call your sh file to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy your sh file at symfony root directory and then run this sh file.

Comment: Give 777 permission to your sh file and try again.

Comment: Please let me know about your result?

Answer (score 0):

In .sh file, Please access your directory then run that command. 
Ex: please use this two steps in your .sh file

```
cd /var/www/project
```

`$ php app/console example:command`